# ORA-00907 when trying to create a CHECK constraint

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, ora-00907

I am trying to create a check contraint on a table by executing the following SQL statement:

```
alter table "ApplicationConfiguration" add
constraint APPLICATIONCONFIGURATION_CK1
CHECK (ValueType IN ('string', 'int', 'decimal, 'date', 'time', 'datetime', 'binary'))
```

but I get the following error:

```
ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis
```

I am completely lost. What am I doing wrong?

Additional information:

- The `ApplicationConfiguration` table
  exists and has a column of type
  `nvarchar(32) not null` named `ValueType`
- Database is Oracle 10g Express
  Release 10.2.0.1.0
- I am executing the
  statement by using the web client
  (Application Express 2.1.0.00.39)
- The database user has DBA rights

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Errormessage is right!

decimal misses a <**'**> at the End in

```
CHECK (ValueType IN ('string', 'int', 'decimal, ...
```

Comment: Uh... I must absolutely take a break. :-(

Answer (score 4):

The error message is unhelpful, but you do have a syntax error - a missing single-quote here:

```
'decimal,
```